# Is it possible to use a dylib completely written in C++ in a Cocoa application

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a dynamic C++ library which does all the back end work. For the GUI I am thinking of using Cocoa. Is it possible to use this C++ library along with Cocoa application. Since usually a Cocoa application is written in Objective-C, I don't know how to combine C++ with objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You combine C++ with Objective C++ in the same way you mix C with Objective C, only the file extension is different: it's `mm` instead of `m`. And if you want your dynamic library to be compiler independent you'll better export the C++ functionality using `extern "C"` (`C` linkage).

Comment: When you give .mm extension compiler treats mix of Objective-c and C++ code that is Objective-C++ code and it compiles.

Comment: extern "C" part is correct, file extension is correct... but mixing C in Objective-C doesn't require anything... so the analogy is poor.

Comment: I edited Objective C to Objective C++ for C++, therefore mixing C++ in Objective-C++ doesn't require anything ... so the analogy is correct :D.